# .NET Core 2.2 Hosting IIS slow after idling

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-10, asp.net-core-2.2

We've started work on a new project where we took the decision to run our first Microservice using .NET Core 2.2 and hosting it in IIS using the "In Process" model.

This has been working rather well, except we've been noticing that after the app has been left idle for a while - I've tracked this down to be > 2 minutes - there is a considerable delay before the next HTTP request comes back with a response. Subsequent responses are near-instantaneous. Leave it again for 2+ minutes, then the next response is slower.

What could be causing this to happen?

IIS's idle timeout is set to 20 minutes, so its not that. I've also looked at the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` type to see if there's anything there, but nothing stands out. I should also make it plain my knowledge of .NET Core is not the best

Edit: The App Pool is already set to `AlwaysRun` and the Site's PreLoad setting is set to `true`

Comment: I'd first start by verifying the process isn't shutting down (check the ProcessID of W3WP.exe).   If that is working, I'd configure IIS to capture a Failed Request Log for requests longer than your expected delay and go check to see what it is doing.

Comment: The w3wp process doesn't shut down, it remains there for the Application Pool's idle timeout setting (20 minutes). Also, the requests do not take so long that it ultimately fails, it does come back after a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

Edit the advanced settings of your App Pool in IIS and change "Start Mode" from "OnDemand" to "AlwaysRunning".

Comment: The App Pool is already set to OnDemand and the site's "Preload" setting is set to `true`

Comment: Stupid brain, yes sorry. That's exactly what I meant to say.